# OSX substitute for <linux/serial.h>

Tags: c++

Currently working on a program that utilises a third party library which was written on linux and includes `<linux/serial.h>`. Is there any easy substitute I can do to make the program work on OSX, or would I have to rewrite the serial code to use another library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much control over the serial port you need.  Both Linux and MacOS/X let you access serial ports via a file descriptor (obtained by a simple call to open() with the appropriate device-path as the argument), so if all you need to do is read and/or write bytes from/to the serial port as if it were a socket, you shouldn't have much trouble.  If you need to do more complex things like enable/disable handshaking and that sort of thing, things will be a little more involved.

FWIW I wrote a simple serial-port interface [class](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/dataio/RS232DataIO.cpp) ([w/header](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/dataio/RS232DataIO.h)) as part of my networking [library](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/); it works under Linux, MacOS/X, and Windows.  You can have a look at it for inspiration if you like; note that the MacOS/X and Linux implementations are pretty much the same except for the method (GetAvailableSerialPortNames()) that enumerates the list of serial devices available.

Comment: "a little more involved" is why some developers include <linux/serial.h> in the first place. Consider adding value by showing which .h is included instead, on MacOS.